# Spacy \ add relaxed pattern with allowed terms between

Tags: nlp, spacy

how can I write regex that will allow words in between
to catch: "hello bla bla bla world" (different numbers of bla can appear anywhere) - do I need write manually IS_ALPHA? I don't know in advanced the number of non-important terms...

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.attrs import POS, LOWER, IS_PUNCT, IS_ALPHA
nlp = spacy.load('en')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
text=u"hello bla bla bla world"


matcher.add_pattern("my regex1", [{LOWER: "hello"},  {IS_ALPHA: True}, {LOWER: "world"}])

doc = nlp(text)


matches = matcher(doc)
print(matches)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't care about the number of `IS_ALPHA` words in between you can use the `*` quantifier, which appears to be specified with the `"OP"` key:

```
matcher.add_pattern("my regex1", [{LOWER: "hello"},
                      {"OP": "*", IS_ALPHA: True}, {LOWER: "world"}])
```

See [test_matcher.py](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tests/matcher/test_matcher.py) from the source for the syntax and [the spaCy docs](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/rule-based-matching#quantifiers) for the available quantifiers.